# Exclude list of string in validation - regex

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I need to validate input: when user type one of 3 words from list (array is in js file), I need to have error (in this case below, if user type test1, test2, or test3 you will see error, otherwise everything should be fine)

file.html

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="regexPatter" />
```

file.js

```
var array = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

var excludeWords = array.join('|')

$scope.pattern = new RegExp("\b(?!\b" + excludeWords + "\b)[a-zA-Z']+\b");
```

I found that this regex pattern should work, but unfortunately, it's problem with '\b' because js misinterprets this char.

How can I replace it? Maybe is another solution for this case? I can't just put this regex pattern in html, because I should add variable.

Thanks for any tip!

Comment: No, it doesn't work, now everything is valid.

Comment: Give a shot with `new RegExp("^(?!.*("+excludeWords+")).*$"`

Comment: @ThomasAyoub great, it works like a charm! It's exactly what I need, but to be honest. I don't understand this code. Can you explain what means those chars? Especially this piece of code: .*("+excludeWords+")). Thanks!

Comment: Then why did you use a regex with word boundaries? It is a classical regex to match a string not containing a word.